# Firestore Reading Old Data

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I've deleted all documents from my collection "Cards". But my old data keeps showing up! I've recently updated my Firebase pods.

Here is my reading data code:

```
CARDS_REF.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("ERROR WHILE FETCHING CARDS: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            var newCards = [Card]()
            guard let snaps = snapshot else { return }
            for snap in snaps.documents {
                let newCard = Card(key: snap.documentID, dictionary: snap.data() as [String: AnyObject])

                let timeStamp = newCard.expirationDate
                let expirationDate: Date = timeStamp!.dateValue()
                let currentDate = Date()

                if currentDate < expirationDate {
                   newCards.append(newCard)
                }
            }

            self.cards = newCards
            self.mainVC?.cardsLoaded()
        })
```

Here is  `CARDS_REF`:

```
let firestoreRef = Firestore.firestore() // <-- Declared outside of class
fileprivate var _CARDS_REF = firestoreRef.collection("cards") // <-- Declared inside DataService class

var CARDS_REF: CollectionReference { // <-- Declared inside DataService class
    return _CARDS_REF
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea Firebase is caching data for you. To disable this, do the following:

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
db.settings = settings // db is your firebase database reference.
```